# LUIS.AI portal keeps reverting the prediction endpoint from the dispatcher model back to starter and disassociates completely endpoint

Tags: azure, azure-language-understanding

When adding a prediction endpoint after creating a new dispatcher LUIS model the model after some time isn't associated to the chosen prediction endpoint. The default goes back to the starter prediction endpoint and causes a lot of problems in our container.

1. I am unsure if this may be a bug but if it is can this be addressed?
2. Is there a way to detect for this and warn against it i.e. like a healthcheck that would be to the prediction endpoint for the luis model.  That is an idea
3. Is there a way to have it not use the starter endpoint because that wouldn't be ideal unless specifically choosing that PEndpoint.

Comment: What do you mean when you say the model isn't associated [with] the endpoint? Are you saying you're trying to query the endpoint and failing? Models are associated with endpoints, they're associated with apps and published to slots.

Comment: i am saying that the prediction endpoint that was added and what is used when you hit the model is removed randomly and the only thing left is the start key.

Comment: Sorry, I meant models *aren't* associated with endpoints. Anyway, what do you mean the endpoint is removed? Do you mean you can't see the desired Azure resource in the LUIS portal? Can you post a screenshot that shows what you're talking about?

Comment: Hi @KyleDelaney I posted the screen shot.  Also, when you say models aren't associated with endpoints? How else would you describe what i am showing? And the error is that the associated / assigned RG randomly comes off?

Comment: I've removed your screenshot because it shows your subscription keys. You need to keep those keys secret, so if you want to post a screenshot like that you need to hide parts of it.

Comment: @KyleDelaney yes thank you so much. I wanted you to see what I was referring to as it has caused a few issues in our development.

Comment: Okay, so what you posted was a screenshot of the Azure Resources section in your Manage tab. A LUIS model is sometimes synonymous with a LUIS app, but it could also be thought of as the data that a LUIS app contains. You do assign Azure resources to LUIS apps, but it is the resources that have the endpoints rather than the model being associated with a particular endpoint. When you query a prediction endpoint the LUIS model that's used is the LUIS model that's been published to that slot, regardless of any current unpublished changes in the LUIS portal.

Comment: The reason I'm saying all this is so that you understand that there's no way for the LUIS portal to "revert the prediction endpoint" because that doesn't make any sense. Please familiarize yourself with the [LUIS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/what-is-luis) so that you can clarify your question using correct terminology. You briefly mention that you're using a container, and if you're talking about the LUIS Docker container then you need to make that the main focus of your question because it changes everything.

Comment: I am quit familiar with the documentation but my impression of what is correct may be mistaken.  I will ask you this question and if I need to edit or ask a different question please let me know.  A. our container keeps failing when trying to make a billing connection (that is the main issue).  B. Seemingly (may be a coincidence) the prediction resource group is sometimes not connected to the luis model.  Now I don't know if that is a coincidence or not but it SEEMS related.  If there is something I am missing from those 2 facts or mistakingly relating them together please let me know

Comment: Also Kyle, we notice F0 429 rate limit errors in luis while this is happening too which further brings us to believe that there is something that something isn't associating correctly.  It could be that is referring to the aurthoring end point but why would that rate limit out?

Comment: The starter key has a much lower prediction limit than an actual prediction key, so that could explain why you're hitting the limit. If you edit the question to include how you're setting up your Docker container and what URL you're using to query your LUIS app (while removing any keys) then that might shed some light on the issue. Also, are you trying to say that your Azure resources are randomly becoming unassigned from your LUIS app?

Comment: Are you still working on this?

Comment: yes this is still an issue.  Happened again today.  It is very random

Comment: Hi, since you are still working on this would you please answer the questions that I asked previously?

Comment: hi Kyle, I think your presumption that "there's no way for the LUIS portal to "revert the prediction endpoint" is perhaps not fully thought-out. That is exactly what it is doing so perhaps if you consider this possibility you perhaps might not understand the issue we are having regarding the prediction endpoint becoming uncoupled from the models that are either the dispatcher model or children models to the dispatcher.  Is there a particular question I am not answering you would like for me to answer. I apologize if I am missing the answer to a question you need.

Comment: Did you see my comment on Jan 21? "The starter key has a much lower prediction limit than an actual prediction key, so that could explain why you're hitting the limit. If you edit the question to include how you're setting up your Docker container and what URL you're using to query your LUIS app (while removing any keys) then that might shed some light on the issue. Also, are you trying to say that your Azure resources are randomly becoming unassigned from your LUIS app?"

Comment: yes kyle it is randomly becoming unassigned that is the entire issue

Comment: What's the LUIS app ID?

Comment: Do you still need help?

Comment: I'm working with Rob for a solution. He is helping so once there's a resolution I'll post the answer. The main issue I think is the container mixed in with this issue

Comment: Rob who? Have you posted this issue somewhere else?

Comment: no he is from the MSFT team that is working with our team for a custom container integration

Comment: @KyleDelaney maybe you could help with this. 2 things. 1. Where is the prediction endpoint hit upon using a container. Meaning are the prediction endpoint settings exported with the container LUIS application upon export. 2. If that is the case (alternative is they are not exported with the container build LUIS export) or Is there a way to verify the export build has the correction prediction endpoint settings upon exporting the LUIS models for the container?

Comment: I can see if you can get that information for you, but did you see where I asked for your LUIS app ID? It may be better for you to email me, both in terms of this thread getting too long and in terms of sharing private information.

Comment: sure what is your email

Comment: You can find it on my profile